# Prove that k has at least two distinct factors other than 1 and k

Tags: proof-explanation

$k = n^3 + 1$ and $n>2$

$n^3 + 1 = (n + 1)(n^2 - n + 1)$

Prove that $k$ has at least two factors other than itself and $1$.

Can someone help me with this proof but not with induction.

Comment: You already have the two factors, $n+1$ and $n^2-n+1$. If you show one fact is not $1$ and not $n^3+1$, it would immediately gollow that bith are. Show $1<n+1<n^3+1$ for $n>1$.

Comment: You also need to show that those two factors are distinct.

Comment: $n+1 = n^2 - n + 1 \iff n^2 - 2n = 0.$  It is given that $n > 2.$